# Потоки в операционной системе

Tags: многопоточность, распараллеливание, ос

Помогите, пожалуйста вот такой вопрос какие есть три основных вида потоков: первый из них это мне сказали, что поток выполнения, а еще два которые есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово поток очень многозначно. И нужно уточнять, что имеют ввиду вопрошающие. В английском чуточку легче. Там есть thread (это поток исполнения) и есть stream (это поток, но файловый). Правда имеют ли эти **stream** отношения к операционной системе - я не знаю.

Правда есть **stream**, которые имеют отношение к винде - [ntfs stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx) - это возможность прицепить к файлу один или несколько потоков (как бы ещё файлов). Это очень любят вирусы.

Также **stream** может означать tcp канал (или любой другой протокол, связанный с интернетом - например, стримминг видео - это видео поток).

Ещё есть [fiber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx) - их также можно назвать "потоками".